# PHP Merging multiple multidimensional arrays while preserving keys and without overwriting other keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out how to merge multiple multidimensional arrays while preserving the keys and not overwriting.

I've got a script that loops and generates one multidimensional array every time it loops. I need to store all those arrays in one new array.

For example

```
$Array1 = Array ( [0] => Array ( [5] => 2 ) );
$Array2 = Array ( [0] => Array ( [6] => Array ( [3] => 4 ) ) );
$Array3 = Array ( [1] => 6 );
$Array4 = Array ( [2] => Array ( [5] => Array ( [3] => 8 ) ) );
$Array5 = Array ( [2] => Array ( [5] => Array ( [4] => 10 ) ) );
$Array6 = Array ( [2] => Array ( [5] => Array ( [5] => 12 ) ) );
$Array7 = Array ( [2] => Array ( [6] => Array ( [5] => 14 ) ) );
$Array8 = Array ( [4] => 16 );
$Array9 = Array ( [7] => Array ( [5] => 18 ) ) 
$Array10 = Array ( [670] => Array ( [5] => Array ( [3] => Array ( [4] => 20 ) ) ) );
$Array11 = Array ( [34] => Array ( [5] => Array ( [3] => Array ( [3] => Array ( [9] => 22 ) ) ) ) );
```

The number of arrays produced defer and the number of dimensions also defer per array.
I need to add them all and generate an array like:

```
$ArrayTotal = Array (
      [0] => Array (
            [5] => 2
            [6] => Array (
                  [3] => 4
                  )
            )
      [1] => 6
      [2] => Array (
            [5] => Array (
                  [3] => 8
                  [4] => 10
                  [5] => 12
                  )
            [6] => Array (
                  [5] => 14
                  )
            )
      [4] => 16
      [7] => Array (
            [5] => 18
            )
      [670] => Array (
            [5] => Array (
                  [3] => Array (
                        [4] => 20
                        )
                  )
            )
      [34] => Array (
            [5] => Array (
                  [3] => Array (
                        [3] => Array (
                              [9] => 22
                              )
                        )
                  )
            )
      )
```

There are duplicate keys, like `$ArrayTotal[2]` but all the keys used to acces the value are always different. For example `$ArrayTotal[2][5][3]` and `$ArrayTotal[2][5][4]` share the first key, but the keys used to get to the value are different.
I've tried using `array_merge` and `array_merge_recursive` and even just adding them using `+`. I've also tried:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($ArrayTotal as $key => $value){
    $out[] = array_merge((array)$ArrayN[$key], (array)$value);
}
$ArrayTotal = $out;
```

Where I looped though all the `$ArrayN`s that where generated. But it overwrites duplicate keys in the first dimension. So it will for example not store `$Array4`, `$Array5` and `$Array6`.
Another small but important detail is, that the keys can be strings.
Like:

```
 $ArrayX = Array ( ["SomeKey"] => Array ( [5] => Array ( ["OtherKey"] => "TheValue" ) ) );
```

My question is:
How can I generate the `$ArrayTotal` as described?

I would prefer something that I can implement in the loop and that adds the arrays one by one.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any logic transforming the values into something else that you neglected to tell us about, or could you just not be bothered to match your example data between in- and output? (Just asking, because [0][6][3] seems to have turned from a 4 to 2, [1] was 6 and is now 3 in your expected output, ...)

Comment: I made a mistake copying the array's, I've edited my question, thx @CBroe

Comment: I don’t think `array_merge` is going to get you very far here. This rather needs a recursive solution, that places the right elements under the right keys at the right level.